# What is the equivalent of `docker create` for Azure Container Instances?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

In Docker, there are `run` and `create` commands. The former creates a new container and immediately run it while the latter just creates without running it. When I create a Container Group in Azure Container Instances, it will immediately run like `docker run`. Is there a equivalent to `docker create` for Azure Container Instances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is, so the alternative would be:

```
az container create xxx
az container stop xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to create a [container instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create) in Azure? in that case you need to use

```
az container create --resource-group
```

and [related commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest)